# Mathematical expression to represent puzzle box solution sequence

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

I'm trying to add a bit of mathematical flair to a japanese puzzle box solution that I am gifting to my friend for his kids.

4 out of the box's 6 sides have movable parts, 2 of those 4 sides have 2 movement possibilities, for a total of 6 possible moves.

The sequence of these movements is 1:6 (1,2,3,4,5,6), repeated four times, followed by movement 1 in reverse (-1), and finally moves 2:3, for a total of 27 moves.

I thought it might be possible to represent this in sequence notation, or as an algebraic function, but I'm having trouble.

Can anyone suggest a direction for this problem? Thank you.

Comment: Maybe group theory can provide a mathematical framework to describe puzzle moves.

Comment: I cannot understand precisely what are the allowed movements. Maybe you can provide  a link describing this puzzle?

Comment: if movement $1$ can be done in reverse, and it's a different movement, then there are not $6$ but actually $7$ movements.  or perhaps every movement can be reversed and there are actually $12$?

Comment: @antkam Yes, every move can be reversed, and must be done in reverse to close the box.

Comment: @Daniel here is a youtube video solving a similar box to the one that I'm speaking of: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9qE68-obwWA

Comment: Why not just $1,2,3,4,5,6,-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6$ then?  Another common notation for inverse is e.g. $X, X^{-1}$.  Or if you prefer letters, A,B,C,D,E,F,a,b,c,d,e,f?  Unless some combinations of moves have the same effects (e.g. doing ABd is equivalent to doing CFea) there is not much group theoretic structure to this.

Comment: @antkam Its really simple if you just look at the sequence of moves, I was hoping to make it a mathematical expression so that the kids would be able to learn some math to solve the sequence of moves which are relatively easy once you know the sequence. EDIT: the moves could be referred to as 1,2,3,4,5,6, -1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6, but the sequence in which they are made is what I was hoping to turn into a meth expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these kids are old enough to know powers, i.e. $x^y$, and you want to sneak in some abstract math, the best (arguably standard?) notation might be styled after group theory. 
 First name the moves $A,B,C,D,E,F$ and their inverses (reverses) $A^{-1}, B^{-1},$ etc.  Then your solution is:

$$(ABCDEF)^4 A^{-1} BC$$

Some potential "teachable moments" :) would include -

- In normal multiplication (of numbers) the order does not matter, but in this notation the order matters.  I.e. $AB$ means doing $A$ then $B$, and is different from $BA$.  (If they know matrices then they know another example of $AB \neq BA$.)
- Even though these abstract objects are not numbers (they are moves), a "thing" raised to an integral power $N$ (here $N=4$) still means multiplying $N$ of that "thing" in sequence.  Here $(ABCDEF)^4 = (ABCDEF)(ABCDEF)(ABCDEF)(ABCDEF)$.  Note that the order matters (see previous point) and this is *not* the same as $AAAABBBBCCCCDDDDEEEEFFFF.$
- For numbers $x (\neq 0)$, we write $x^{-1}$ to mean $1/x$ (and you can explain *why* this notation makes sense: it preserves the rule of $x^m x^n = x^{m+n}$ when e.g. $m=3, n=-1$).  For abstract objects we can still write $A^{-1}$ if multplying $A \times A^{-1}$ (i.e. doing $A$ followed by its inverse) equals do-nothing (equivalent to $1$ being the multiplicative identity).

If they aren't old enough to know powers, convert everything to addition and use instead:

$$4 \times (A+B+C+D+E+F) + (-A) + B+C$$

but again explain that order matters ($A+B \neq B+A$), what $\times$ and $-$ mean when you are dealing with abstract objects (not numbers), etc.

But here's my most sincere recommendation: Do not, under any circumstances, ruin the enjoyment of the puzzle by forcing math on them, making them think: $math \neq fun$!

Comment: This is perfect, thank you! Regarding your last point, these kids love math, so I think it would augment their entertainment as oppose to ruining it, but thank you for the wise comment nonetheless.